# show/hide div when textarea typed in? IE9 Compatible Method

Tags: javascript

im trying to find a way to dispay a div when a user types in the textarea field and then hide the div when they take the text out again.

I am using IE 9 and it must be compatible with that, although i am having a lot of trouble finding a script that IE 9 supports. 
I did find this script which works in JSFiddle on my IE 9 browser

link: http://jsfiddle.net/THkqE/

but not when i try and code it into my site myself like so:

```
    <head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#cname").on('input', function() {
           $('#cname2')[this.value.length > 8 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
       });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" class="field">
<div id="cname2">cname2</div>
```

css:

```
#cname2{
display:none;
}
```

can someone please show me what i am doing wrong, thanks

Comment: Is this what you are asking ? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THkqE/1/)

Comment: ive tried ur demo and doesnt work in IE9, i am using IE9 so the code must be supported by IE9